# dereference and suffix ++ precedence

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-precedence, postfix-operator

```
int a[3]={10,20,30};
int* p = a;
cout << *p++ << endl;
```

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), suffix `++` has higher precedence than dereference, `*p++` should run `p++` first and then dereference and the result should be 20, but why the actual result is 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p++` uses the postfix increment operator. I.e., it increments `p`, but returns the value that was present **before** incrementing. In other words, this is equivalent of doing something like this:

```
int a[3]={10,20,30};
int* p = a;
int* q = p;
++p;
cout << *q << endl;
```

When styled like that, it's obvious why `10` is printed.
If you want to increment `p` and print its dereference, you could use the prefix increment operator:

```
int a[3]={10,20,30};
int* p = a;
cout << *(++p) << endl;
```